# What is the 80s-90s sci-fi book series about training gifted kids to teleport loads between planets?

Tags: story-identification

I remember the cover of the first book in the 3 or 4 book series has a picture of a beautiful white/silver haired young girl in a blue dress.  The story is about children who are identified as gifted teleporters being trained to "shift" loads of whatever between planets....could be food and provisions, or personnel carriers etc.  They have to have someone to "throw" and someone to "catch" and set down at the other end.  Would love to read it again.

Comment: Something about Talents. Definitely Anne McCaffrey.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

This is likely *The Tower and The Hive* series by Anne McCaffrey.

The universe has a high level of technology, but the only way to crack faster-than-light travel is through the use of psychic powers.  Specifically, psychics powerful enough to teleport ships and cargo through thought alone.  A psychic powerful enough to run a starport is usually called a Prime Talent.

The first book in the series is *[The Rowan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Rowan)*, here's the plot synopsis off of Wikipedia:

> The Rowan tells the life story of a young orphan, of Prime Talent, from the moment the child's community is wiped out in a mudslide to the time when she becomes a Prime and after a life of loneliness falls in love with a previously undiscovered Prime on Deneb which was being attacked by aliens.

The cover matches your description too:
[image]

Comment: Thanks so much......that's it!!

Comment: On a side note, her series [Dragonriders of Pern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dragonriders_of_Pern) is a fantastic series that combines elements of fantasy and sci-fi brilliantly.